# Store a Action<T> in dictionary

Tags: c#, generics

What I have is a asynchronous request/response model, when the response is received I want to run an action.

A small code sample of what I'd like to accomplish:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        //Make a request and show 'hello world' when the response was received
        Connection.Request<MyResponse>("key", (MyResponse) => {
            Console.WriteLine(MyResponse.Value);
        });

        //set the response making the action write "hello world"
        Connection.SetResponse("key", new MyResponse("hello world"));
    }
}

public class Connection {
    static Dictionary<string, Action<BaseResponse>> _dicActions = new Dictionary<string, Action<BaseResponse>>();
    public static void Request<T>(string key, Action<T> action) where T : BaseResponse {
        _dicActions.Add(key, action);
    }

    public static void SetResponse(string key, BaseResponse pResponse) {
        _dicActions[key](pResponse);
    }
}

public class BaseResponse { }
public class MyResponse : BaseResponse {
    public string Value;
    public MyResponse(string pValue) {
        Value = pValue;
    }
}
```

Of course in the sample above the _dicActions.Add doesn't work.
How could I make the below code work?, for some reason haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: The explanation for CS1661 error you see is https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq/ - you can set `Action<Derived>` to instance of `Action<Base> baseAction` (because that `baseAction` will always be called with instance of "Derived" which is definitely "Base", but the other way it does not work because not every "Base" is "Derived".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this properly you really have to ensure that the dictionary is type-safe. This is simple to do. Just change the dictionary from `Dictionary<string, Action<BaseResponse>>` to `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<Type, Delegate>>` and then implement `Connection` like this:

```
public class Connection
{
    static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<Type, Delegate>> _dicActions = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<Type, Delegate>>();
    public static void Request<T>(string key, Action<T> action) where T : BaseResponse
    {
        if (!_dicActions.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            _dicActions.Add(key, new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>());
        }
        _dicActions[key].Add(typeof(T), action);
    }

    public static void SetResponse<T>(string key, T pResponse) where T : BaseResponse
    {
        ((Action<T>)_dicActions[key][typeof(T)])(pResponse);
    }
}
```

That works with your existing code like a treat and it ensures that you don't mismatch your `key` and your `T` when calling `SetResponse`.

Comment: Nice. In production code consider it you want to add some null check in `SetResponse`, also there is a good chance that NRE is actually correct in this case as I'd expect set of handlers should match set of responses and missing handler is actually bug rather than expected behavior.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Yes, I would generally put in null check code in here. It's just a bit simplified for easier understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `Action<BaseResponse>` directly?

```
public static void Request<T>(string key, Action<BaseResponse> action) where T : BaseResponse
```

Or you can make the class generic:

```
public static void Main()
{
    //Make a request and show 'hello world' when the response was received
    Connection<MyResponse>.Request("key", (MyResponse) => {
        Console.WriteLine(MyResponse.Value);
    });

    //set the response making the action write "hello world"
    Connection<MyResponse>.SetResponse("key", new MyResponse("hello world"));
}

public class Connection<T> where T: BaseResponse
{
    static Dictionary<string, Action<T>> _dicActions = new Dictionary<string, Action<T>>();
    public static void Request(string key, Action<T> action)
    {
        _dicActions.Add(key, action);
    }

    public static void SetResponse(string key, T pResponse)
    {
        _dicActions[key](pResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its also worth noting, the generic parameter is redundant now and also the OP will have to cast `Console.WriteLine(((MyResponse)MyResponse).Value);`

Comment: Because when doing that I'd have to cast the parameter in the action to MyResponse, I'd like to avoid casting as this prevents developer mistakes and is cleaner.

Comment: @Crazy seems like making the Connection class generic solves the problem as ojlovecd suggests

Comment: It does indeed solve the issue, added it into my application and works as intended

Comment: @Crazy creating a lot of sibling types with generics may not be what you want... (like you no longer can have collection of "Connection" instances) as long as it works for you and you understand what is actually going on then all good.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, that was indeed the reason I switched to the answer Xiaosu gave. The answer Enigmativity gave required me to refactor a little bit but is better as it's type safe.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to make a smaller change in your code, you can convert the action like this:

```
_dicActions.Add(key, o => action((T)o));
```

Comment: Sure... Also moving compile time errors to become run-time errors is rarely good idea.

Comment: It does work with minimal changes, also requires less refactoring on my end. Why would i be getting run-time errors?, casting to T can't really make anything go wrong right?

Comment: @Crazy I've added explanation on the question already. Read it carefully. It is not possible to say if it applies to your particular case but for code shown so far it can easily fail at run-time: you try to call `Action<MyResponse>` with instance of `MyOtherResponse : BaseResponse`

Comment: This is such a bad idea - it's is throwing away type-safety.